# What are the 'subtle changes' in Google Spreadsheets API?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Google is [upgrading old spreadsheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6082736) to the new version of Google Sheets.

This is beginning to screw up a web service I'm running that uses the Google Spreadsheets API. I need to quickly make some code changes so it understands the new API, but I don't know where to start.

The above linked  has only this to say:

> APIs — You may notice some subtle differences in API behavior.

What are these 'subtle differences'? Why can't I find a list of what has changed?

Comment: Sorry this is happening to you.  You likely already saw it, but they have a forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/docs/spreadsheets

Comment: Interesting, I did not notice any changes, all worked the same on both new an old style sheets, maybe they fix an outstanding bug or two. There is an issue list for the "Spreadsheet-api" https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list?q=label:API-Spreadsheets - 
Note I am using cellfeed, not listfeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one thing that changed is it no longer suports the old way of authenticating. You now have to use OAuth. I think this is where my problem was.